# Common lisp read from FIFO with timeout

Tags: common-lisp, fifo, sbcl

So I have some code like

```
(let ((file (open cur-fifo :if-does-not-exist :create)))
  (format t "~A~%" (read-line file nil))
  (close file))
```

Which as far as I can tell works fine, except that this will block indefinitely if no data was written to cur-fifo. I want the read to time out and return NIL if no data could be read in ~0.1 sec or so.

Running on SBCL 1.1.18, on 64-bit Gentoo Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [FIFO model](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe)

When you `open` a `fifo` special device (for reading), the system call *blocks* unless either

- the fifo is already opened by (another) process for writing OR
- you pass `O_ASYNC` to `open(2)` - which you might not be able to do in your implementation unless you use a low level package [`sb-posix`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#sb_002dposix)

When you successfully *opened* the fifo, your `read(2)` call will block until your counterparty (that opened the fifo for writing, which could be the same lisp process) *writes* something there.

## Common Lisp

What you are looking for is [`listen`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_listen.htm) (see also [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm)):

```
(with-open-file (fifo "my-fifo" :if-does-not-exist :create)
  (when (or (listen fifo)
            (progn (sleep 0.1)
                   (listen fifo)))
    (format t "Read [~A]~%" (read-line fifo))))
```

## Debugging

Please note that special device handling is not necessarily equally well supported by all CL vendors.
If the above does not work, please do some experiments with the REPL: open the `fifo`, see what `listen` returns, write something there, see what `listen` reports now, &c.

If `listen` still returns `nil` even though you already wrote something into the pipe, this might mean that your CL does not recognize the file as a special device. You might have to pass some implementation-specific arguments to `open`, e.g., `:buffering nil` or something (try `(describe 'open)`).

Comment: In case this wasn't obvious from the code, the file I'm reading is a FIFO (i.e. a named pipe, created with `mkfifo`)

Comment: @KahrKunne: please see my edits. please edit your question to add vendor details.

Comment: Notice that it's the `OPEN` that blocks when trying to open an empty FIFO, not the `READ-LINE`. I've never used FIFOs, so I'm not familiar with them, but I don't think there's any way around it besides reading it in a separate thread.

Comment: @jkiiski: this depends on the CL implementation (and the implementation-specific options to `open`)...

Comment: Edited question with vendor details. Some experimentation shows that it's indeed `OPEN` blocking if there's nothing connecting to the FIFO. Thinking about it again, this is not too surprising - a FIFO isn't really a "file" so much as it is a connection between two programs; it wouldn't really make sense to be able to `OPEN` a pipe when it's not connecting to anything.
Multithreading doesn't really fit my program flow right now, so I'll try a different method of IPC, rather than FIFOs

Comment: I am sorry, I did not realize your level of experience with pipes, I will edit my answer now.

Comment: I've come up with a better solution to the bigger problem that doesn't require me to read multiple FIFOs in a loop, so blocking doesn't bother me anymore, i.e. I don't need this question answered anymore. What is proper StackOverflow etiquette for this situation?

Comment: @KahrKunne: close the question by [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439) an answer and move on.